# Save specific attributes of json list

Tags: python, json

I have this json file, with this structure:

```
{
"vendors": {
    "vendor": [
        {
            "estminutes": null,
            "pestm": null,
            "deliveryfee": 0.00,
            "minimum": 1.00,
            "distance": null,
            "duration": null
         },
        {
            "estminutes": null,
            "pestm": null,
            "deliveryfee": 0.00,
            "minimum": 1.00,
            "distance": null,
            "duration": null
         }]
 }
```

I would like to know, how can I only save the attributes deliveryfee and duration. And remove the other ones

Expected Output

```
{
"vendors": {
    "vendor": [
        {
            "deliveryfee": 0.00,
            "duration": null
         },
        {
            "deliveryfee": 0.00,
            "duration": null
         }]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have loaded your JSON into a dictionary called `data`, you can process the `vendors` element using a nested dictionary/list comprehension, with an `if` test to ensure you only keep the keys you want:

```py
[ { k : v for k, v in vendor.items() if k in ['deliveryfee', 'duration'] } for vendor in data['vendors']['vendor'] ]
```

Output:

```
[
  {'deliveryfee': 0.0, 'duration': None},
  {'deliveryfee': 0.0, 'duration': None}
]
```

That result can then be assigned back to `data['vendors']['vendor']` or a new variable as required.